# In Android Studio how do you add a different Manifest file for each product flavor?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have two product flavors. Here is the app gradle:

```
flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors{
    publicVersion{
        dimension "default"
    }
    privateVersion{
        dimension "default"
    }
}
```

I want a different Manifest file for each flavor. So I created a Manifest file with the path src/publicVersion/AndroidManifest.xml and a different one with the path src/privateVersion/AndroidManifest.xml, then I deleted the main Manifest file.

After I did that nothing worked. Android Studio is still demanding there be a Manifest file in the main directory. I tried all the answers on SO (like using "sourceSet" in the app gradle file) but they didn't work. Perhaps recent Android Studio updates have changed the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

**OPTION 1**

Have `AndroidManifest.xml` for each flavour

- app/src/flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml
- app/src/flavor2/AndroidManifest.xml
- app/src/flavor3/AndroidManifest.xml

---

**OPTION 2**

Move the permissions into the product-flavor-dependent `AndroidManifest.xml` and leave the Activities and all other common information in one core `AndroidManifest.xml`

`app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` contains common information about Activities, … but no permissions

```
<manifest  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- permissions are imported via brand-specific AndroidManifest.xml -->

<!-- common manifest elements -->
<application
    android:name=".ui.FSApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <!-- activities -->
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.SecondActivity/>

    <!-- receiver ->
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.BlogPostReceiver"/>

</application>
</manifest>
```

`app/src/flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml` contains only permissions for the flavor1 product flavor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Similarly for flavor2 in `app/src/flavor2/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

For more info check [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-product-flavor-dependent-permissions)

Comment: In Option 1 you still have to have a Manifest in the main directory

Comment: In Option 2 why do activities need to be in the main Manifest file?

Comment: you would put everything that is valid for all flavours in the main Manifest and the specialties in the flavours. This can both be activities and permissions, while activities do not hurt to be in all flavours you might not want to declare unnecessary permissions in some flavours.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the complete manifest in the individual flavours or define only the specialties in the flavours (IMHO better). If you add a permission in one flavour only, you only need to have a Manifest there with this single permission and it will be merged with the main permissions. If you want to modify an XML-Tag you can use `tools:node="merge"` and `tools:node="replace"`.

Comment: Hi I think I understand everything except "tools:node="merge" and tools:node="replace"". Can you give an example?

Comment: as you have the `<application>` tag in your `main` flavour and maybe in your individual flavour, you need to use `tools:node="merge"` so the the system will merge the content of the two versions. If you want to replace a tag, you use `replace`